# ckeditor, how to adjust the wrap code display styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I'm testing out [CKEditor](https://ckeditor.com/)

I'm trying to get the display in the editor, to match my sites css style for displaying the end result.

What I'm trying to do is style the "wrap code" button to match the css of my site, by adding in a class.

I've seen on [this page of the manual](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_format-section-custom-block-level-text-formats-definition), that you can do stuff like this:

```
config.format_pre = { element: 'pre', attributes: { 'class': 'editorCode' } };
```

However, doing the same for a code block like so:

```
config.format_code = { element: 'code', attributes: { 'class': 'someclass' } };
```

Doesn't actually do anything. Anyone got a pointer on what I might be missing?

I've tested it working on other elements, so I know the config file changes are being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

The one important thing is that every tag which is formatted via `config.format_tagname` should be also included in [`config.format_tags`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-format_tags). However, this two settings (`config.format_tagname` and `config.format_tags`) works only form Block-Level elements (as stated in the [manual page](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_format-section-custom-block-level-text-formats-definition) you referenced ).

As `code` element is considered as an inline one by CKEditor (see [DTD](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd)), it is not possible to use this config here.

However, the easiest way to modify the elements added via Style dropdown is to edit `styles.js` file which is present in CKEditor directory. The dropdown styles are based on this file, so you can easily modify [`code` element there](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/styles.js#L68). You can also define your custom [`stylesSet`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-stylesSet).